# Как написать в инпуте и поле для ввода и кнопку действия как на картинке?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, form

[image: Как сделать такие поля?]

Конкретно интересует  как красиво так же прилепить Кнопку-изменить-сохранить

Comment: Странно что вопрос закрыт как "невозможно дать лаконичный ответ". особенно если учесть, что на него дан вполне лаконичный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый же запрос в гугле дал [результат](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-sdelat-knopku-vnutri-polya-dlya-poiska)

```css
input {height: 1.2em;}
input[name="q"] {padding-right: 1.8em;}
input[type="image"] {
 left: -1.8em;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<form action="//google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input name="q" />
    <input type="image" src="//google.com/favicon.ico" />
</form>
```

Думаю вам не составит труда сверстать текст, вместо картинки.